# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. for pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having trouble converting a pandas series with arrays to a numeric type.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"vector" : [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]]})
```

And then both:

```
df.vector.astype("float16")
df.vector.values.astype(np.float16)
```

Result in

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This workaround:

```
np.array([x for x in df.vector.values]).astype("float32")
```

Works.

What is the issue with a regular astype cast using a list of lists based on a pandas series?

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas` works best with scalar values, so if use `lists` of `arrays` solution is a bit complicated, because `astype` convert only scalars:

```
df['vec1'] = [np.array(x).astype(np.float16) for x in df.vector.values]
print (df)
            vector                          vec1
0  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]  [0.099976, 0.19995, 0.30005]
1  [0.4, 0.5, 0.7]         [0.3999, 0.5, 0.7002]

a = np.array(df.vector.values.tolist()).astype(np.float16)
print (a)
[[ 0.09997559  0.19995117  0.30004883]
 [ 0.39990234  0.5         0.70019531]]
```

Comment: This does seem more like a workaround than a solution. Is this a feature or rather a bug in pandas? What is the root cause of this exception?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I say not implemented yet? And reason is (in my opinion) problematic vecorized, especially if each array has diferent length.

Answer (score 0):

Since the element you're looking to convert in the DataFrame is a list within a Series, you'll need to add iteration to the Pandas version of the vector operation. You can do this with `apply` and `map`:

```
df.vector.apply(lambda x: map(np.float16, x))
```

Output:

```
0    [0.099976, 0.19995, 0.30005]
```